# Unit test for multiple unknown outcomes

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Considering the following code, or any code really how would I write a test that tests for a  string OR a null value?  The string doesn't have to be anything specific just basically is it a string?

```
public string BuildNumber()
{
    using (PropertyGetter getProperty = new PropertyGetter())
    {
        return getProperty.GetString("BuildNumber", "Win32_BIOS");
    }
}

public class PropertyGetter
{

    public PropertyGetter() { }

    public string GetString(string propertyName, string Win32Class)
    {
        ManagementObjectSearcher moSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher
            ("SELECT " + propertyName + " FROM " + Win32Class);
        using (var enu = moSearcher.Get().GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (!enu.MoveNext() || enu.Current[propertyName].ToString() == null)
            {
                return String.Empty;
            }
            return enu.Current[propertyName].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should write two tests - one for each desired output you are expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The empty string and null are two different values, so it's two separate test cases. Therefore, you should **write two tests**.

Actually, if you want to test the `GetString` method, there are two string arguments in play, so that's **four possible combinations**.

However, if the expected outcome is the same for all four combinations, if you have a decent unit testing framework, you can write a **Parameterized Test**:

```
[Theory]
[InlinedData("", "")]
[InlinedData("", null)]
[InlinedData(null, "")]
[InlinedData(null, null)]
public void MyTest(string propertyName, string win32Class)
{
    // Pass propertyName and win32Class into the GetString method here
    // and make an assertion on the result
}
```

This example uses [xUnit.net](https://xunit.codeplex.com).

Comment: Thanks.  Your answer was very helpful.  However I believe I need to be a it bit clearer in my question regarding the string values.  Though they can be null and or empty the can also be anything such as "stuff"  "things"  whatever really.  How do I test for that?